# Break a table content so half only displays by clicking on "View More"

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is too long and I would like to add a small row in the middle to "View more".
Just like the accordeon option work but with a table.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImYFx.jpg)

Right now this is the html and css I use:

```css
.dailyingredientsgrid {
  display:grid;
  border: solid 1px;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 6fr;
  width: 100%;
}

.dailyingredientsdetails{
display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  border-right: solid 1px;
}

.dailyingredientspowders {
display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dailyingredientsgrid">
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Camucamu_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367195" alt="camu camu powder" width="" height=""></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails"><p style="text-align: left;">Vitamin C powerhouse for immune balance, mood, and respiratory health.*</p></div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maca_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368191"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails"><p>Adaptogenic power root for stamina, sexual vitality and stress response.*</p></div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Cacao_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368254"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails"><p>Antioxidant-rich booster for cognitive function, mood and skin health.*</p></div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Green_Papaya_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368308"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Nutrient-dense team player for digestion, circulatory and sexual health.*</div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Chaga_low_1000_72_2.png?v=1589367483"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Adaptive defense ally for immune response, anti-aging and protective wellness.*</div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maqui_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368365"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Anthocyanin-rich catalyst for sustained energy, skin health and anti-aging.*</div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Ginger_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367279"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Dynamic antimicrobial for digestive, innate immune, and microbiome health*</div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Camucamu_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367195" alt="camu camu powder" width="" height=""></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails"><p style="text-align: left;">Vitamin C powerhouse for immune balance, mood, and respiratory health.*</p></div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maca_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368191"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails"><p>Adaptogenic power root for stamina, sexual vitality and stress response.*</p></div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Cacao_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368254"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails"><p>Antioxidant-rich booster for cognitive function, mood and skin health.*</p></div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Green_Papaya_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368308"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Nutrient-dense team player for digestion, circulatory and sexual health.*</div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Chaga_low_1000_72_2.png?v=1589367483"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Adaptive defense ally for immune response, anti-aging and protective wellness.*</div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maqui_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368365"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Anthocyanin-rich catalyst for sustained energy, skin health and anti-aging.*</div>
<div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Ginger_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367279"></div>
<div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Dynamic antimicrobial for digestive, innate immune, and microbiome health*</div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: @Vega no I would like the rest of the content to appear only after clicking on a "view more" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically set `max-height` depending on a conditional:

```js
expandHeight = () => {
  const grid = document.querySelector('.dailyingredientsgrid');
  const showMore = document.getElementById('show-more');

  if (showMore.innerHTML === 'Show More') {
    grid.style.maxHeight = 'unset';
    showMore.innerHTML = 'Show Less';
  } else {
    grid.style.maxHeight = '500px';
    showMore.innerHTML = 'Show More';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dailyingredientsgrid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 8px;
  border: solid 1px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 6fr;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dailyingredientsdetails {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  border-right: solid 1px;
}

.dailyingredientspowders {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}

#show-more {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#show-more:hover {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="dailyingredientsgrid">
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Camucamu_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367195" alt="camu camu powder" width="" height=""></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p style="text-align: left;">Vitamin C powerhouse for immune balance, mood, and respiratory health.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maca_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368191"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p>Adaptogenic power root for stamina, sexual vitality and stress response.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Cacao_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368254"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p>Antioxidant-rich booster for cognitive function, mood and skin health.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Green_Papaya_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368308"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Nutrient-dense team player for digestion, circulatory and sexual health.*</div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Chaga_low_1000_72_2.png?v=1589367483"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Adaptive defense ally for immune response, anti-aging and protective wellness.*</div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maqui_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368365"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Anthocyanin-rich catalyst for sustained energy, skin health and anti-aging.*</div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Ginger_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367279"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Dynamic antimicrobial for digestive, innate immune, and microbiome health*</div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Camucamu_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367195" alt="camu camu powder" width="" height=""></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p style="text-align: left;">Vitamin C powerhouse for immune balance, mood, and respiratory health.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maca_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368191"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p>Adaptogenic power root for stamina, sexual vitality and stress response.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Cacao_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368254"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p>Antioxidant-rich booster for cognitive function, mood and skin health.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Green_Papaya_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368308"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Nutrient-dense team player for digestion, circulatory and sexual health.*</div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Chaga_low_1000_72_2.png?v=1589367483"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Adaptive defense ally for immune response, anti-aging and protective wellness.*</div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maqui_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368365"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Anthocyanin-rich catalyst for sustained energy, skin health and anti-aging.*</div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Ginger_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367279"></div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">Dynamic antimicrobial for digestive, innate immune, and microbiome health*</div>
</div>
<button id="show-more" onclick="expandHeight()">Show More</button>
```

Comment: This does it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript to do this.

Initially, hide all the grid items by setting `display: 'none'` in CSS. Using javascript, set `display: flex` on first few rows to show them initially. Show more grid items as "view more" button is clicked.

When all the rows have been shown, view more button is hidden.

**P.S.** I have removed some of the grid items for this demo.

```js
const imgContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.dailyingredientsdetails');
const textContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.dailyingredientspowders');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

let limit = 2;
let currentIndex = 0;
const numRows = imgContainers.length;

function viewMore(index) {
  for (let i = index; i < index + limit && i < numRows; i++) {
    imgContainers[i].style.display = 'flex';
    textContainers[i].style.display = 'flex';
  }

  currentIndex += limit;

  if (currentIndex >= numRows) {
    btn.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => viewMore(currentIndex));
viewMore(currentIndex);
```

```css
.dailyingredientsgrid {
  display: grid;
  border: solid 1px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 6fr;
  width: 100%;
}

.dailyingredientsdetails {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  border-right: solid 1px;
}

.dailyingredientspowders {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fc3;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="dailyingredientsgrid">
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Camucamu_low_1000_72.png?v=1589367195" alt="camu camu powder" width="" height="">
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p style="text-align: left;">Vitamin C powerhouse for immune balance, mood, and respiratory health.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maca_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368191">
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p>Adaptogenic power root for stamina, sexual vitality and stress response.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Cacao_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368254">
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    <p>Antioxidant-rich booster for cognitive function, mood and skin health.*</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Green_Papaya_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368308">
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    Nutrient-dense team player for digestion, circulatory and sexual health.*
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Chaga_low_1000_72_2.png?v=1589367483">
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    Adaptive defense ally for immune response, anti-aging and protective wellness.*
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientspowders">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1109/4348/files/Powders_Maqui_low_1000_72.png?v=1589368365">
  </div>
  <div class="dailyingredientsdetails">
    Anthocyanin-rich catalyst for sustained energy, skin health and anti-aging.*
  </div>
</div>

<button>View More</button>
```

You could tweak javascript code to fit to your need.